# In what way can each <li> in a <ul> change its classname without affecting the others?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

There is going to be an unusual amount of code here because I am trying to share everything that is going on.

What I am trying to do is... In a list:

1. Mark services as complete.
2. Change their color and hide after completion.
3. Show hidden services on a button press.

I managed to hide each individual service, but couldn't work with the button that hides/shows all of the completed services.

I have a context provider:

```
const ContextBooking = React.createContext()

const ContextProviderBooking = ({ children }) => {
  const [isHidden, setIsHidden] = useState(false); //sharing among both components to hide/show list

  return <ContextBooking.Provider value={{ isHidden, setIsHidden }}>
    {children}
  </ContextBooking.Provider>
}
export { ContextBooking, ContextProviderBooking }
```

Which is being passed over the BookingsDisplay component in another file

```
...
<ContextProviderBooking>
      <BookingsDisplay /> //this encapsulates each <Booking />
</ContextProviderBooking>
...
```

I am rendering each of the services in a larger component called 'BookingsDisplay'

```
const BookingsDisplay = () => {
  const { isHidden, setIsHidden } = useContext(ContextBooking)  
  const display = day => //function that displays each service according to the day it was booked for
    allBookings.map( //allBookings is a json file
      item =>
        item.day === day && ( 
          <Booking
            isHidden={isHidden}
            completed={item.completed} //comes from json file, all default to false
            key={item.id}
            id={item.id}
            time={item.time}
            name={item.name}
            date={item.date} 
          />
        )
    )
  return (
    <div className="bookings">
      <h2 className="ib">Next bookings</h2>
      <button //This won't work as expected and hide/show all of the 'completed' bookings
          onClick={() =>{ 
            setIsHidden(!isHidden);}
      }>
          Show hidden  
      </button>
      <h2>Today</h2>      
      <ul> {display('today')} </ul>
      <h2> Tomorrow </h2>
      <ul> {display('tomorrow')} </ul>
      <h2> General </h2>
      <ul> {display('other')} </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Each 'Booking' component has a button that marks the service as complete. This happens by conditionally changing the class of each component. This works fine as far as I'm concerned

```
const Booking = (props) => {
  const [isHidden, setIsHidden] = useState(props.isHidden)
  console.log(props.isHidden) // will output true or false 16 times(there are 16 component in total)
  const [isCompleted, setIsCompleted] = useState(props.completed);
  return (
    <li
      className={
        isCompleted && isHidden ? 'booking-complete hide' //class names are not changing individually
        : isCompleted ? 'booking-complete'                //if button is pressed on one of them,
        : 'booking'                                       //it may affect the other
      }
      key={props.id}
      id={props.id}>
      <h3>{props.date}</h3>
      <h4>{props.time}</h4>
      <h5>{props.name}</h5>
      <button
        onClick={() => { //shouldn't this button work of each li and not sometimes all of them?
          if (!isCompleted && !isHidden) { 
            setIsCompleted(!isCompleted); //this changes color of the service as className changes
            setTimeout(() => setIsHidden(!isHidden), 200) //after a short time it is hidden
          }
          else if (isCompleted && !isHidden) {
            setIsCompleted(!isCompleted);
          }
          else {
            setIsCompleted(!isCompleted);
            setIsHidden(!isHidden);
          }
        }}>
        {!isCompleted ? `Completed` : `Not complete`}
      </button>
    </li>
  )
}
```

Comment: Maybe the click is being triggered on multiple events. Place a debug on each event to check that

Comment: what are the 'events' in my code? I don't know where to place the debugger

Comment: The `onClick` functions

Comment: I have some questions... do you have two Booking components? where is the array of the services (JSON and not in store...) ? and I think that your state are reset every time you click the button that make the component rerender with the default useState of `isHidden = false`

Comment: @Omer I have a 'Booking' and a 'Bookings' component (just edited it, thanks). The Bookings component displays all of the individual Booking ones. The JSON file is at a folder in the directory for now to simulate a database. how to go about fixing the button?

Comment: first the 'Booking' and a 'Bookings' are NOT good names.. I used name like 'TodoList' and 'TodoPreview' or 'TodoListItem' thats more clear (BookingList,
BookingItem).
second in the init upload app, you have to copy the data in the JSON to state management like ContextAPI or Redux or MobX.. and onClick update the array of the bookings.

Comment: Where do you call `React.createContext` to initialize ContextBooking? I think you may be using Contexts wrong here.

Answer (score 6):

There're two kind of `isHidden` in your app. I'mma call the one in context the *global hidden* `isAllHidden` and the one in `<Booking />` the *local hidden* `isHidden`.

The problem is you misuse the two. *local hidden* is an internal state of `<Booking />`. The reason of it's existence is because you need that 200ms delay of animation, otherwise it can be replaced by `isCompleted`. So it should be derived from `isCompleted` instead of `isAllHidden`.

Fix 1:

```
const Booking = (props) => {
  const [isHidden, setIsHidden] = useState(props.completed)
}
```

Now *global hidden* and *local hidden* combine to decide whether a Booking should hide. You logic should reflect this fact.

Fix 2:

```
  const shouldBeHidden = Boolean(props.isAllHidden && isHidden)

  return (
    <li
      className={
        isCompleted && shouldBeHidden ? 'booking-complete hide' 
        : isCompleted ? 'booking-complete'on one of them,
        : 'booking'other
      }
    >
  ...
```

Put together:

```
const Booking = (props) => {
  const [isHidden, setIsHidden] = useState(props.completed)
  const [isCompleted, setIsCompleted] = useState(props.completed)

  const shouldBeHidden = props.isAllHidden && isHidden

  return (
    <li
      className={
        isCompleted && shouldBeHidden ? 'booking-complete hide' //class names are not changing individually
        : isCompleted ? 'booking-complete'                //if button is pressed on one of them,
        : 'booking'                                       //it may affect the other
      }
    >
      <input type='checkbox' checked={isCompleted} onChange={() => {
        setIsCompleted(!isCompleted)
        setTimeout(() => setIsHidden(!isHidden), 200)
      }}/>
      <span>{props.name}</span>
    </li>
  )
}
```

I setup a [demoboard](https://frontarm.com/demoboard/?id=17ed9dbb-bdd6-456c-8e78-38f2d9c418be) here to show the result.